# Запись данных из .json файла в JTable

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, swing

У меня есть `.json` файл типа:

```
`[
{"email":"example1@gmail.com",
"name":"USer1"},
{"email":"example2@gmail.com",
"name":"User2"},
{"email":"example3@gmail.com",
"name":"User3"},
{"email":"example4@gmail.com",
"name":"User4"}
]`
```

Надо взять только `email` и вывести на таблицу,
файл выбираю через `JFileChoser`

Comment: Что не получается? Есть какие-то наработки?

Comment: @Chubatiy наработок нет, в том то и дело даже не знаю как начать я выбираю файл .json через OpenDialog и с выбраного файла надо закинуть данные в таблицу, есть метод для создание таблицы private void createDefaultTableModel(Object[][] email) { this.defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(email, headers); userEmailAndName.setModel(defaultTableModel); }

Comment: Делаете класс с полями `email` и `name`. Полученный `String` из файла перегоняете, к примеру, как `new Gson().fromJson(text, new TypeToken<List<Имя вашего класса>>(){}.getType())`. На выходе имеете список(`List`) строк вашего Json, который потом проеобразуйте в массив и в ваш метод по отрисовке

Comment: @Chubatiy я пытался через `ObjectMapper()` 
`File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    ListEmails emails = mapper.readValue(new File(selectedFile.getPath()), ListEmails.class);
                    Object[][] objects = {{emails.getEmails()}};
                    createDefaultTableModel(objects);`